# Setting up absoute imports for storybook and weback from scratch

Tags: webpack, storybook

I'm trying to to create a ui library as a separate package for my app. For this I set up a package from scratch creating a `package.json` and running `npx storybook init` in it.

When running storybook I seeing a log of errors:

> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> /Users/xxx/Code/nl/node_modules/utils/general.jsx doesn't
> exist
> .ts

`utils/general` is not a package but a file I'm trying to import from an absolute path. Yet, webpack does not seem to be able to resolve it.

I'm using `storybook`s default webpack config and defined by `baseUrl` in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "include": [
      "src"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "src",
      "outDir": "lib",
      "declaration": true,
      "jsx": "react",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true
    }
  }
```

This does not work, however. I'd love to resolve my absolute imports correctly. I'm happy for any help.

Answer (score 0):

(Solution for future reference)

```
module.exports = {
    stories: [
        '../src/**/*.stories.mdx',
        '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    ],
    addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials'],
    typescript: {
        reactDocgen: 'react-docgen-typescript',
    },
    webpackFinal: async (config) => {
        config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'));
        return config
    },
};
```

refere to: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/4136